# How to make this particular blender material in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, transparency

I've seen this material which has been made using blender rendering's engine, and I'd like to give it a fresh look in Cycles.

Here is a screenshot of the nodes and the previewed material :
[image: The material I'd like to "convert" towards Cycle]

However, I tried using Layer Weights but the layers(white then blue) were not correctly applied to the subdivided Icosphere.

Plus in Cycles, I don't know how to use the alpha output since there is none on the material output node when using Cycle rendering engine.

I am a bit of newbie towards this, usually, I try things on the node editor, and they work out fine but this time, I really don't know what to do.

So if someone could explain to me, how to make this particular material using Cycle(even like if it's a bit more realistic), I'll be glad to take it as well as an explanation of the process during the making of it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Instead of thinking of "alpha" you should look fot the Transparent shader. Could you please show your result with the subdivided icosphere in order to exactly understand why you are not satified with the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do that in cycles the set up would look like this:

The layer weight node controls the falloff for blue and white respectively in combination with the color ramp to clamp the falloff.

Of course the transparent node is to cutout the center, you might also want to play with the roughness on the glossy shaders, it will give you a different look .

[image]

Comment: Can we make the whole material appears more brighter it feels like it's fading off, I guess the transparency is affecting the borders too much, can't we control it more precisely for the center only?

Comment: You can't control the center so you have to mess around with the layer weight and color ramp nodes. The layer weight will control the "fading off" part and the color ramp will control how thick the white and blue parts are.

Comment: Also the roughness in the glossy nodes can help with the "fading off" part

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'm messing with it right now, but I can't seem to get the proper result, I've added an Emission shader also to get it to be brighter but there are black borders between the white and blue.

Comment: By Replacing the glossy shaders with Emission shaders, I got a better result, thanks the setup.