# Making a material fade off(progressive transparency from front to back) based on the location of its geometry

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency, geometry

I'd like to make this object half transparent, on one side and half atmosphere-looking in the front.

Here is what I'd like to look like :

[image: What I'd like it to looks like]

Here is what I currently have :
 [image: Material and object I have currently]
Also note that the geometry is like this :
[image: Geometry of the object]

The inner part of the object is the light emissive part, and the outer region is for the atmosphere, I gave them both different materials, I want the effect I am talking about on the outer material.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPvYAHc9vCE I use an empty to control where the texture is affecting the transparency.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

This is the same set up from your previous [Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102684/how-to-make-this-particular-blender-material-in-cycles/102687?noredirect=1#comment182100_102687) what was added was a gradient texture node added to the beginning of the chain of nodes. I put the color ramp node so you can control where the falloff to transparency ends.

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I tried a render with this precise settings at first I thought it was okay, it was exactly what I wanted but now we don't know where the front of the bullet is in relation to where the back of it is.I think I find it out after messing around a bit with the geometry and the material, it was simple actually. Also, I'm sorry I misexplained what I actually wanted.I'll probably answer my question someday, thanks for the help.